# What “nice one” (possibly an expression) really means?

Tags: phrase-usage, phrase-meaning

I heard it in Diana the movie.

Someone tells the surgeon “nice one” when they meet in the stairs.

I am not sure if we need context here or if it is just an idiomatic expression in English (or perhaps just an expression in British English).

Comment: I don’t think Nice one! is American usage at all, but I hear it all the time in British crime dramas. Latest example: Trigger Point by the people who did Line of Duty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Nice one* is quite informal and has a couple of meanings. It's often followed by *mate*, (a friendly form of address between men) in BrE and AuE as in *Nice one, mate*. In AmE the term *buddy* could be used instead of *mate*.

When used in the positive it means *Well done* or *Thanks* (or both) here's a few typical examples.

> You take your car to the garage to have the brakes fixed, when you pick it up the engineer says *'The brakes are done and we also adjusted your clutch'*, You reply *'Nice one'*. This is the *well done and thanks* meaning.
>
> You are in the pub and someone buys you a drink, when they give you the drink you say *'Nice one'* This is the informal *thanks* meaning.
>
> You are watching football and someone scores a good goal. You say 'Nice one'. This is the informal *well done* meaning.

All of the above are positive and likely to be what you heard in the movie but it's possible to use *Nice one* in a negative way. Here are a couple of examples.

> You are in the pub and someone spills your drink. You say *'Nice one'* but you mean *That was stupid and careless of you*.
>
> You are telling a long joke to a friend and another friend cuts in and says the punchline long before the punchline should be said. You can say *'Nice one'* to express your disgust at your friend spoiling the joke.

You can really only tell the difference between positive and negative *Nice one* by the context and more so by the tone of voice used by the speaker.

I wouldn't say it was specifically British English, Australians definitely use the positive version and as noted in the comments Americans use both the positive and negative meaning but might not use it for *thanks*.

Comment: Americans also say "Nice one" as a compliment meaning that someone has done a good job -- just like your example of seeing someone score a goal. Or sarcastically to mean that someone has made a clumsy mistake. I don't think an American would say "nice one" to mean "thank you". And of course an American would never say "nice one, mate" as we don't call each other "mate". Might say, "Nice one, buddy".

Comment: @Jay Nice one. I've updated to include that info.

Comment: In those positive examples, I think you may be more likely to hear a single word ("Nice!") than the two-word counterpart ("Nice one!") – at least in the U.S. My gut feeling is that, by including the word "one", the expression has a somewhat negative tone overall, but of course there are exceptions.

Comment: @J.R. In BrE _nice_ would also be OK, as would _super, great, brilliant, magic_ and a host of other words; most, if not all, would work for the positive and negative meanings.